# How To open thickbox, onclicking Tinymce Button with dynamic content from ajax

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, thickbox

I have added a tinymce button to my tinymce editor.but instead of opening the tinymce default modal (`editor.addCommand`),I want to open Thickbox with ajax content.I have searched many answers on stackoverflow, but didn't make it out.

### Here is my code

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('smart_event', function( editor, url ) {
        var shortcode_tag = 'smart_event';

        editor.addCommand('smart_event_panel_popup', function( ui, v ){
            var columns = '4';
            if(v.columns){
                columns = v.columns;
            }
            var style = '';
            if(v.style){
                style = v.style;
            }
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Smart Event Shortcode',
                body: [

                    //...........

                ],
                onsubmit: function(e){
                    // var scode = '[' + shortcode_tag +' columns="' + e.data.columns + '"' + ' style="' + e.data.style + '"' + ' posts_per_page"'+ e.data.posts_per_page +'"' + ' sortby="'+ e.data.sortby +'"' + ' range="'+ e.data.range +'"' + ' pagination="'+e.data.pagination + '"' +' filters="'+e.data.filters + '"' +']';

                    editor.insertContent( scode );
                }
            });
        });


        editor.addButton('smart_event', {
            image: seventadmindata.imagesurl + 'icon.png',
            tooltip: 'Insert Smart Event Shortcode',
            onclick: function(){
                editor.execCommand('smart_event_panel_popup','',{
                    columns : '4',
                    style : '1',
                });
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

How can I add Thickbox on click with an ajax callback?